# Custom Tab Bars in swift and xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, tabbar

I have created a custom tab bar with some of my own images for the individual tabs. However, the images are far too large for the tabs. Is there any way I can resize these images either programatically or through Xcode's own utilities so that they will be in the correct dimensions for the tabs?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode does not allow to resize images. I think it is better to resize image manually, not programmatically. [This link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) describes the iOS icon standard sizes. You can easily resize images with standard Preview.app.